# iPhone-SDK:Tab bar item images are not visible

Tags: iphone

I created a Tab Bar Controller which has 5 tab bar items. I am trying to add images for all the items through interface builder. I am also able to choose images and set for the particular tab bar items. But whenever i set an image, it does show blank white screen instead of the complete image. P.S: My image is not corrupted, it is a good image. My image size is 24*24. I am not creating tab bar controller items programmatically.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images must be PNGs with transparency, and only the mask is used.  See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html